# Iterating through a context in parallel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

As I understand Working with a `DataContext` in Parallel is not thread-safe but only if you declare your context as `static` (Based on MSDN documentation)
This is what I did, once I found it worked and the other time it failed !

**MSDN :**
Thread Safety
"Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx

It seems that I'm getting the usual error related to `DataContext` and it's **Thread-Safety lack**.

Here I explain a bit what I want to do, and what is my desired result, hope got expert's help and ideas on this case.

I want to do heavy analysis processes on about 100,000 records,

The error is :

> EntityMemberChanged or EntityComplexMemberChanged was called without first calling EntityMemberChanging or EntityComplexMemberChanging on the same change tracker with the same property name. For information about properly reporting changes, see the Entity Framework documentation.

Pointing to this line in the Designer code :

```
            ReportPropertyChanged("ProductName");
```

**What is in my Code :**

```
    //On form Load
    if (Repository.ContextP == null)
          Repository.ContextP = new dbEntities();

    private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         Process(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning); 
    }   

    private void Process()
    {
        var query = from W in Repository.ContextP.Products
                select W;

        Parallel.ForEach(query, options , product =>
        {
           // There are some heavy processes to get stFormattedDef
           product.ProductName= stFormattedDef;               
        }
     }

     // The Repository - static
     static class Repository
     {
         public static dbEntities ContextP { get; set; } 
     }
```

Security and Data Context Life-time shouldn't be a problem cause the the analysis is in the build-phase and it's local.

What I did wrong?

Any suggestions?

Ideas or experiences in similar cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework and multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574329/entity-framework-and-multithreading)

Comment: was that related to static DataContext ? and a Life-time opened Context ? (during application life cycle) ?

Comment: Did you read the Thread Safety warning incorrectly?  instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe

Comment: In my first 2 sentences : "if you declare your context as static (Based on MSDN documentation) This is what I did", so it's static and not instanced object

Comment: Ahh... gotcha.  Sorry, I misread what your question was saying.

Comment: @Sypress But that's not what the warning says. It doesn't talk about where do you keep your `DataContext`, that wouldn't make any sense. What is says is that instance members of `DataContext` (like `Products`) are never thread-safe.

Comment: it specifically states: The ObjectContext class is not thread safe. The integrity of data objects in an ObjectContext cannot be ensured in multithreaded scenarios.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get a piece correctly, or did something wrong, I'm posting the missed part

Comment: Why are you even try to execute this in parallel? Parallelization makes sense if what you're parallelizing takes a lot of time, which isn't the case here.

Comment: What could be my best choice, a practical alternative that could run my code through it, cause if I want to choose a Context-Per-Thread scenario I'll miss the result of my iteration.

Comment: @Svick , Yesss, really I need performance on the processes I want to do with the entities, the processes are really heavy, and I estimated it will take about 1 whole day if I won't do some performance thricks, I think it could be possible to reduce it to about 2 hours.

Comment: @svick also thanks for the piece of info clarifying the misunderstood part for me, But do you have also any suggestions to make this work the job ?

Comment: I didn't still be sure about the idea here, I think what I said could be right, cause In MSDN it's talking about DataContext that should be static which I did, not talking about each entities, Am I right ? , Here the instance of DataContext is ContextP in the Repository which is static the same as the container(Repository class), Although are making changes regarding Thread-Safety to see the results, Now added another piece to the question which should complete the view of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know EF, but from the question and comments, I think the problem is that you can't set `ProductName` from different threads at the same time, even if it is for different `Product`s (because they all use the same non-thread-safe `DataContext`).

So, my advice is to run the expensive operation in parallel, but then make sure to set `ProductName` only from one thread at a time. The simplest way to achieve that is to use a `lock`:

```
var productLock = new object();

Parallel.ForEach(query, options , product =>
{
   // There are some heavy processes to get stFormattedDef

   lock (productLock)
   {
       product.ProductName = stFormattedDef;
   }
}
```

Like I said, I don't know EF, so I don't fully understand the problem. Because of that, this might not be the right solution.

Comment: Thanks svick +1 sharing your idea in this case locking I think could be an option here which when I tried got another exception and it's related to EF again : "Cannot perform the update operation because the adapter's connection is not open.", I'm still playing around with it to see the best solution suite my needs.

Comment: But the problem will occur in some lines below the previous error at the time of saving the context during a transaction, I think the error could be from the current strategy we chose

Comment: Anyway thanks, I'm trying to deal with all the possible alternatives to see when I could get the best results.